# Matching elements of two vectors based on proximity

Tags: r

I got two vectors:

```
a<-c(268, 1295, 1788, 2019, 2422)
b<-c(266,  952, 1295, 1791, 2018)
```

I want to match the elements of b to the elements of a, based on the smallest difference. So a[1] would be matched to b[1].
However, each element can only be matched to a single other element. It is possible that elements cannot be matched. If two elements of b have the smallest difference to the same element in a, then the element with the smaller difference is matched.

For example 952 and 1295 are closest to element a[2], as 1295 is closer (in this case even equal to) a[2] it would get matched with 1295.
The final solution for this particular example should look like this.

```
268  NA  1295 1788 2019 2422
266 952  1295 1791 2018 NA
```

Some of the item are not matched and although it would be possible to match 952 and 2422 the code I need would not considere them a match because matches were found inbetween them. The vectors are also strictly increasing.

With my coding capabilities I would use tons of if statements to solve that issue. But I was wondering whether this is a know problem, and I am aware of the terminology of such or if someone would have an idea for an elegant solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R approach, although probably not the most elegant one:

```
aux1 <- apply(abs(outer(a, b, `-`)), 2, function(r) c(min(r), which.min(r)))
colnames(aux1) <- 1:length(b)
aux2 <- tapply(aux1[1, ], factor(aux1[2, ], levels = 1:length(a)),
               function(x) as.numeric(names(which.min(x))))
rbind(cbind(a, b = b[aux2]), cbind(a = NA, b = b[-aux2[!is.na(aux2)]]))
#         a    b
# [1,]  268  266
# [2,] 1295 1295
# [3,] 1788 1791
# [4,] 2019 2018
# [5,] 2422   NA
# [6,]   NA  952
```

---

Here `aux1` contains closest `a` elements to `b` (2nd row) and the corresponding distances (1st row).

```
tmp
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2  343    0    3    1
# [2,]    1    2    2    3    4
```

Then `aux2` may already be enough for your purposes.

```
out
#  1  2  3  4  5 
#  1  3  4  5 NA
```

`aux1` showed some ties but `aux2` now gives which element of `a` (2nd row) should be assigned to which element of `b` (names). Then in the last line we bind the rest of the elements.

---

In a more complex case we have

```
a <- c(932, 1196, 1503, 2819, 3317, 3845, 4118, 4544)
b <- c(1190, 1498, 2037, 2826, 3323, 4128, 4618, 1190, 1498, 2037, 2826, 3323, 4128, 4618)

# ....

rbind(cbind(a, b = b[aux2]), cbind(a = NA, b = b[-aux2[!is.na(aux2)]]))    
#          a    b
#  [1,]  932   NA
#  [2,] 1196 1190
#  [3,] 1503 1498
#  [4,] 2819 2826
#  [5,] 3317 3323
#  [6,] 3845   NA
#  [7,] 4118 4128
#  [8,] 4544 4618
#  [9,]   NA 2037
# [10,]   NA 1190
# [11,]   NA 1498
# [12,]   NA 2037
# [13,]   NA 2826
# [14,]   NA 3323
# [15,]   NA 4128
# [16,]   NA 4618
```

Comment: Thanks so much, really awesome, I have some more combination of such vectors if I struggle I might  have to get back to you :)

Comment: @Tim, no problem, I'm glad it works well. Sure, then it's best to post a new question (as it's most likely going to be different enough from this question), and I'll take look if no one else does before me!

Comment: Hey so when I have another set of 2 vectors:
of unequal length `a<-932 1196 1503 2819 3317 3845 4118 4544` and 
`b<- 1190 1498 2037 2826 3323 4128 4618`. The same rules are applying, and the cumsum is throwing only NA's. I believe it is because of the intial value of the input vector for cumsum is also an NA's. I really never used cumsum before but maybe you know a workaround.

Comment: @Tim, see the update, seems to be fine for both cases now, right?

Comment: Hey, yes I did not see that you edited it already. Thanks so much it really helped me